# Write a python program that will take a string as input from the user. The input string should have a combination of BOTH the alphabets and the digits

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

Write a python program that will take a string as input from the user. The input string should have a combination of BOTH the alphabets and the digits. Then, your task is to identify the digits from that input string and store those digits in a list. Finally, sort the list and print the sorted list and the sum of digits as output to the user.

**Sample input 1**  m4gt567q09y2

**Sample Output 1**  ['0', '2', '4', '5', '6', '7', '9']

33

**Sample input 2** 954217

**Sample output 2** There's no alphabet in the string.

I tried doing this far. my code can only satisfy the 1st sample input.But I can't figure out any way to satisfy the sample input 2. I have provided my code below

```
string1=input("Enter the string: ")
output_list=[] 
sum=0
flag= False
for i in range(len(string1)):
   if string1[i].isdigit():
       output_list.append(string1[i])

output_list.sort()
print(output_list)
for i in output_list:
    sum+=int(i)
print(sum)
```

Comment: you can just check if output_list is the same length as the input

Comment: Reopened as the target was *"How do you check in python whether a string contains only numbers?"*, whereas this question is *"How to find number in a string that must contain alphabetical characters?"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`str.isalpha()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) method will return `True` is a string is all alphabetical characters, and the [`str.isdigit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) method will return `True` if a string is all digits:

```
string1 = input("Enter the string: ")
if any(map(str.isalpha, string1)):
    output_list = [i for i in string1 if i.isdigit()]
    print(sorted(output_list))
    print(sum(map(int, output_list)))
else:
    print("There's no alphabet in the string.")
```